# Map Array data and prepend to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamanoopchandran/81764174/2/) which basically takes an array data and appends it to HTML. I have used `for` loop to achieve this. But I'm curious if I wanted to do this using `Array.prototype.map()` function, how would I do it? I don't want to use any third-party library like underscore or lodash.

Comment: Functional programming (usually) avoids side effects like DOM manipulation.  So I would say that using `map` isn't really a great choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Solution:**

Since OP is saying that he doesn't have control over the **input**, which `data` as it is provided by wikipedia (probably 1 of their services)

Then I am assuming that the data is structured and correct, that is it will never have a case where 1 of the nested array is longer or shorter than the other.

Yes, you definitely can use the `map` API to give more meaning to the input you got from Wikipedia and then do a `forEach` to iterate over the items to build your HTML string.

**Example:**

```
var data = [["title 1","title 2","title 3"],
    ["description 1","description 2","description 3"],
    ["link 1","link 2","link 3"]];

var titles = data[0];
var descriptions = data[1];
var links = data[2];

var output = titles.map((title, index) => {
    return {
        "title": title,
        "description": descriptions[index],
        "link": links[index]
    }
});

output.forEach((item) => {
      $("#output").append(
          "<div><h1>"+ item.title +"</h1><p>"+ item.description
          +"</p><a>"+ item.link +"</a></div>"
      );
})
```

See JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SamuelToh/8tpb1jsg/

---

**Previous Solution:**

First of all - I think the way chosen data structured is prone to error because there is no clear relation on how title1, description 1 and link 1 forms a set.

What if 1 of the array goes out of sync? That is, 1 of the array is shorter or longer than the rest, in that way your code would die of `index out of bond` on runtime.

I think ideally you will want your data to be structured like;

```
var suggested_data = {
    title1: {
        description: "description 1",
        link: "link1"
    },
    title2: {
        description: "description 1",
        link: "link1"
    },
    title3: {
        description: "description 1",
        link: "link1"
    }
}
```

In this way you say title X has the description property with value of yyy and link property of value zzz.

Even when one of these properties are missing, at the very most you get an `undefined` value.

And this is how you would loop through the structure

```
for (var title in suggested_data) {
    var item = suggested_data[title];
    $("#output").append(
          "<div><h1>" + title+"</h1><p>" + item.description
          +"</p><a>" + item.link + "</a></div>"
      );
}
```

Ultimately it is not about using `map` or not, I think it is more of the data structure you have chosen.

Comment: I was trying to build a wikipedia viewer and the json data is formatted this way.. Check this out...  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="cats"&format=json&callback=?"

Comment: @anoopchandran thanks for the update. As I wasn't aware that you didn';t have control over the input. Alright now I have updated the solution to do `map` and then `forEach`. Tried it on fiddle and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could gather the new HTML elements in an array using `.map()`, and only then append that result to the output element in one operation.

Note that you should use the `.text()` method, instead of concatenating strings, to avoid that greater-than signs or ampersands destroy the resulting HTML.

Here is how it would look like:

```js
var data = [["title 1","title 2","title 3"],
            ["description 1","description 2","description 3"],
            ["link 1","link 2","link 3"]];

$("#output").append(data[0].map( (title,i) =>
    $("<div>").append(
        $("<h1>").text(title),
        $("<p>").text(data[1][i]),
        $("<a>").text(data[2][i])
    )
));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

NB: When you actually want use the third value as a hyperlink, then use `.attr()`:

```
$("<a>").attr('href', data[2][i]).text('click here')
```

Or you might just hyperlink the first (title) value:

```
$("<div>").append(
    $("<h1>").append(
        $("<a>").attr('href', data[2][i]).text(title)
    ),
    $("<p>").text(data[1][i])
)
```